# Running a script in the context of an HTML custom element

Tags: html, custom-element

I'm writing some HTML5 custom elements which contain code that gets transpiled so that it can actually run on the page (graphics code, latex, etc), but I can't seem to find any page, or Stackoverlow question, that explains whether and how to load a script such that it's scoped to the custom element itself.

Instead, all I can find is "no information at all" so I'm using the somewhat silly "insert it in the document head, rewritten so that it first grabs the right element from a global registery", which is super dirty. I works, but it would be much nicer to be able to inject scripts in the shadow DOM in a way that runs them, with a knowledge of exactly which element they're running for.

Right now, the code (in reduced form) looks like this:

```js
import { uuid } from "./uuid.js";
import { Parser } from "./code-parser.js";

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.uid = uuid.v4();
    window[this.uid] = this;

    const jsCode = `
      import { Base, API, ... } from "./lib.js";
      class Example extends Base {
         constructor() {
           super(window[${this.uid}]);
           delete window[${this.uid}];
         }
         ${Parser.rewrite(this.textContent)}
      }
      new Example();
    `;

    const script = document.createElement(`script`);
    script.type = `module`;
    script.src = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([jsCode], {type: `text/javascript`})
    );

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(script);
  }
}

customElements.define(`my-element`, MyElement);
export { MyElement }
```

This works, of course, but works by (temporarily) polluting `window`. Is there a way to attach a script element to a custom element, or custom element's shadow DOM, such that it executes with a knowledge of which custom element, or which shadow DOM, it's running for?

**Edit:** to be explicit, this needs to work for scripts that use modern code that relies on [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules): any `import` statement still needs to resolve. Also note that anything that relies on approaches that require[`unsafe-eval`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-script-src) (6.1.11.3) or [`unsafe-inline`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) to be added to the [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) `script-src` directive cannot be used.

Comment: Why do you think you have to append a new <script> element? If only for the `import` statements, you can very well convert these to dynamic `import()` calls and execute all from the constructor, very normally and very cleanly.

Comment: because the code in the actual script does not exist anywhere. It's dynamically generated. The code exists as string data, gets rewritten to proper JS and _then_ gets injected. There is no fully formed module to import.

Comment: (I'm working on this over on https://pomax.github.io/custom-graphics-element, in case you want to understand the full chain of events, which are not relevant to this question, but might be relevant to your interests)

Comment: Sorry I don't really have time to check your repo entirely, but fast reading it, you don't need to have these scripts executed in <script> elements. You can simply generate your dynamic "scripts" using the `new Function()` constructor. Something like `const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor; new AsyncFunction(\`const API = await import("./api.js"); const Base= await import("./base.js"); ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't: sane CSP (e.g. without `unsafe-eval`) disallows `eval()`, `new Function()`, and the little known string execution forms of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. This element is intended to run on arbitrary sites, so this has to still work on sites with normal CSP in place. Needing `unsafe-inline` right now is already fairly questionable, and I'll probably have to switch this to a `src="blob:..."` injection instead. Irrespective, the original question still stands: how can a script injected into a shadow DOM get a reference to that shadow DOM, or the shadow DOM's owner?

Comment: A sensible suggestion in the absence of details, though, so I've updated the post to make it clear that `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` are off the table, with the code updated to use blob injection instead.

Comment: So you are actually trying to eval non script content as scripts in a CSP blocked context. Even blob:// URIs would be blocked by a `script-url: 'self'` rule. I think you have to refactor a bit your project. A few solutions (all less appealing than others) come to mind: 1) Define your own language, parse it from these <program-code> contents and execute it in your own engine. 2) Make a non-dynamic pre-builder tool that your users would have to call to generate a built file. 3) force the use of unsafe-eval. (I think 1&2 are actually what similar projects like react do).

Comment: They would be, but most CSP isn't just `self`, they're also protocol and domain whitelists, and `blob:` as part of a CSP is not too uncommon, whereas no one in their right mind would add `unsafe-eval` to their CSP list. As for the suggestions, 3 is obviously not happening, and while 1 and 2 are possible, they both have drawbacks that are far more severe than the _currently working_ solution that relies on temporary global pollution. It sounds like you're confident that there is no way for a script to ever learn which shadow DOM it's in: with spec-based motivation that would make a good answer.

Comment: Why would one in their right mind allow blob:// for scripts but not unsafe-eval? Both lead exactly to the same risks...

Comment: then we have different ideas about what CSP's use actually is, and we're also heavily derailing this comment thread: do the various specs around shadow DOM and custom elements suggest how scripts of `type="module"`, inserted into a shadow DOM, can find their shadow root? Because I can't find anything anywhere that explains how that might happen. If you know (or if you know that it's explicitly impossible), then an answer that I can mark as accepted would be appreciated. Alternate approaches are off the table: this question is _explicitly and only_ about a script injected into a shadow DOM.

Comment: Would love to add any of my points to the bounty. But I don't think there is an answer because (unlike when using IFRAMEs or Workers) the __*fundamental*__ problem *?* is: ``<SCRIPT>`` **"in"** shadowDOW is not scoped **to** shadowDOM. It executes in global scope.

Comment: Right: that would _literally_ be the kind of answer I want to see so I can accept it, if that can be backed up with links to the (various) spec(s) that clarify that this is the intended behaviour. And then your "how to hack your way around that" answer is a great "not answer, but super useful information" post in addition to something that can be accepted so that future visitors with the same problem know what the state of affairs is.

Comment: I never found anything related but Rob Dodson his blog that had one line on this: *"script isn't scoped"* and Supersharp his answers here on SO (saying script isn't scoped). Maybe make it an issue on https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues

Comment: I should. I originally filed https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5754 for this, but its hard to know what the best place is to file issues around things that seem to fit in at least four different repos across two different orgs.

Answer (score 2):

### Update #2

Work around below will not work if CSP is in play
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

---

---

You can inject a `SCRIPT` element, but certainly not plain sailing.

Problem is the `SCRIPT` gets the `window` *scope*, not your Custom Element *scope*.

**Disclaimer:**
*Code below works on Chredge and FireFox.

But my gut feeling says there is a potential issue, I just can't put my finger on it*

To pick up the correct *scope* you have to add a TAG that does know its location in the shadowDOM, and can get the Custom Element with `.getRootNode().host`

`<style onload=console.log(this)>` is a candidate, but for some reason it will only execute for one Element on the page

So I switched to `<img src onerror=console.log(this)>`

The SO snippet below can't handle this code properly.
Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/qmtugp4v/

```html
<template id=scriptContainer>

  <!--start-->
    <script>
      console.log("script",this); // window
      function run(scope) {
        const element = scope.getRootNode().host;
        element.ran();
      }
    </script>
    <img src onerror="run(this)">
  <!--end-->

</template>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
            .append(scriptContainer.content.cloneNode(true));
      }
      ran() {
        const pre = document.createElement("PRE");
        pre.innerHTML = this.shadowRoot.innerHTML.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
        this.shadowRoot.append("shadowRoot content: " , this.id , pre );
      }
    });
</script>
<my-element id=ONE></my-element>
<my-element id=TWO></my-element>
```

## Update #1

Yes, I knew something wasn't quite right

```
   function run(scope) {
     const element = scope.getRootNode().host;
     element.ran();
   }
```

Becomes a `window.` **Global** function, overwritten by every new `my-element` in the page.

Code still works, just don't store any local (Element) stuff in the function.
And maybe give it a very obscure function name.

### Execute added SCRIPT with correct Custom Element scope

To not create globals, stuff all code as IIFE in the IMG `onerror` (INLine script!!),
the arrow function ensures the correct scope:

```js
  <img src onerror="(()=>{
    this.onerror = null;// prevent endless loop if function generates an error
    const element = this.getRootNode().host;
    console.log('IIFE',element);
  })()">
```

**OR** as Custom Element method:

```js
  runScript(script) {
    const span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    const onerror = `this.onerror=null;const element=this.getRootNode().host;` + script;
    span.innerHTML = `<img src onerror="${onerror}">`;
    this.shadowRoot.append(span);
    setTimeout(()=>span.remove());
  }
```

call: `` this.runScript(`console.log(666,element.id)`); ``

**Playground in: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/qmtugp4v/**

**outputs:**

[image]

The IMG IIFE runs in the correct scope

The last 2 console lines come from:

```
TWO.runScript(`console.log(${this.id}.id,'runs in',element.id)`);//duplicate line in console!
TWO.runScript(`console.log(${this.id}.id,'runs in',element.id)`);//duplicate line in console!
```

demonstrating the script runs **in the correct scope** when you call that `runScript` method on a Custom Element

Comment: Hm, if getting the script to even execute at all what inserted into the shadow dom, that might open a way to possibly get the right scope, let me see if I can play with your first code a bit to get that to work, too.

Comment: played around with this some more, but the problem isn't really getting the script to run "at all", it really is the whole "how the heck does it find its "owner" without having to go through `window`" =(

Comment: That is why the IMG is needed, it will trigger the ``onerror`` (or ``onload``) event with the correct *this* scope (the IMG) So from there you can do ``this.getRootNode().host`` Play  the JSFiddle I linked to. Yes it is a Workaround with capital W. But it Works

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that's not actually the case though: if I run the unmodified jsbin, I see console logs that say the script for ONE runs in TWO (two logs), and that the script for TWO runs in TWO (also two logs), so it looks like this doesn't reliably work when more than one instance of the custom element exists on the page.

Comment: I added a screenshot above; Essential part is the IIFE logs **with the correct scope** Those ``TWO.runscript`` lines are a bonus; they create **4** log lines **all 4 running in element TWO scope** demonstrating that the script runs in the correct scope when you call ``element.runScript( ... )`` That ``runScript method is not required, I added it to show extensibility. I know this IMG/scope workaround works; have used it for many years in the MS-SharePoint world, where we had limited script injection possiblities

Comment: Correction: From SharePoint 2001 till 2016 you could **not** inject JavaScript at all IN data columns... But you could add HTML .. and Microsoft did not do any XSS checks.. so IMG.onload or IMG.onerror was a way to *'get in'* In later versions Microsoft switched to all React.

Comment: Right, but therein also lies the problem: old tech worked with old tricks for old specs, but I need something that relies on new (2 years old by now, but new in comparison) features: the scripts I need to run use `import` statements, and so can't be inlined via `on...` attribute, the code in the `on...` handler would somehow need to get the element scope and then get that scope added into code loaded via a script element with `type="module"` (unless you know a sneaky to inline module code anyway, of course. That'd be awesome)

Comment: So you have two issues: (**1**). How to get the scope (answer: done with IMG workaround) and (**2**). How to transfer scope to a module function. --- The latter will only work if the module has an "entry" ``function( )`` which can be defined with ``.bind``  or called with ``.call`` or ``.apply`` But that means refactoring scripts to kinda oldskool patterns.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out things get even more fun than initially considered, because we also have to consider another feature of the modern web: CSP. So issue (3) is that solutions here cannot violate CSP policy around `script-src`, which means no `unsafe-inline` and no `unsafe-eval`, which rules out this technique entirely even if it works on an unrestricted page =(

Comment: more fun? Less fun. CSP is a condom.

Comment: Unfortunately, markdown has no sarcasm syntax. Also: yeah, that's pretty much exactly what it is. A sensible CSP is about as effective as a properly applied condom: both will stop easily preventable problems the vast majority of the time. So as much as an annoyance they are, still better used than not ;)