# `document` doesn't refer to the shadowDom

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

So I have code that's something like this:

```html
<template id="cool-btn-template">
  <script>
    const button = document.getElementById('click-me');
    button.addEventListener('click', event => alert(event));
  </script>
  <style>
    #click-me {
      all: unset;
      background: tomato;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: white;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }
  </style>
  <button id="click-me">Log click event</button>
</template>

<cool-btn></cool-btn>

<script>
  class CoolBtn extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const template = document.getElementById('cool-btn-template');
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }

  customElements.define('cool-btn', CoolBtn);
</script>
```

If you run the code, you'll notice that `document` in the template's script tag refers to the overall document, not the shadowDom. How do I make `document` mean its shadowDom?

Comment: Moving that inline script into your class declaration will help you scope it to the element

Comment: @Sean, thanks, but is it possible to scope the DOM to the template? I making a simple component framework that needs script tags to be scoped correctly to their templates.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `document` would be scoped to the shadow root in the shadowDOM? I can find no reference that suggests that.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027122/running-a-script-in-the-context-of-an-html-custom-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all JavaScript for a custom element is meant to go inside its class, which is how you scope it to the element:

```html
<template id="cool-btn-template">
  <style>
    #click-me {
      all: unset;
      background: tomato;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: white;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }
  </style>
  <button id="click-me">Log click event</button>
</template>

<cool-btn></cool-btn>

<script>
  class CoolBtn extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const template = document.getElementById('cool-btn-template');
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
      shadowRoot.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', event => alert(event))
    }
  }

  customElements.define('cool-btn', CoolBtn);
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. It seems like there should still be at least an option to scope scripts to their templates.