# How to contain a window object inside shadow-root

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow-dom, shadow-root

I have added a `script` element inside the `#shadow-root`. The problem is that when the `window` object is used inside the `b2.js` file, it still refers to the parent application's `window`. Is there a way to scope the `window` object that is used inside the `script` file to the `#shadow-root` exclusively.

Example dom:
[image]

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027122/running-a-script-in-the-context-of-an-html-custom-element/63030202#63030202

Comment: Hi @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, thankyou very much for the reply. This appears to be pointing towards the right direction. I have experimented with the example in the question but the ```window``` object still appears to be pointing to the parent application. The root of my problem is that I am inserting external scripts which use the ```window``` and ```document``` objects and need to get access to the elements inside the ```#shadow-root```. Is there any way to get the ```window.document``` object to point to the inside of the ```#shadow-root```. The example you provided only proves it for scope.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Understood. Might you know of another alternative other than iFrames which could potentially facilitate segregated ```window.document``` variables.

Comment: every DOM has one ``window.document``